# Object reference not set to an instance of an object when calling a function

Tags: vb.net

I call the function GetDataTable and when it gets to the return line, I get the error message:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
Dim DB As New DBConn
Dim gd As New DataAccess.GetData
Dim DT As New DataTable

Dim repotid1 As Decimal = 1150
Dim startdata1 As DateTime = "6/1/2012"
Dim EndDate1 As DateTime = "6/12/2012"
Dim StartDate3 As DateTime = "11/1/2011"
Dim Enddate3 As DateTime = "5/1/2012"

Dim sql1 As String = String.Format("EXEC [dbo].[usp_GetReportData_All] @ReportID=N'{0}', @StartDate=N'{1}' @EndDate=N'{2}', @StartDate2=N'{3}' @EndDate2=N'{4}'", repotid1, startdata1, EndDate1, StartDate3, Enddate3)

DT = DB.GetDataTable(sql1)

Public Class DBConn
Dim gd As New DataAccess.GetData

Public Function GetDataTable(ByVal sql As String) As DataTable

    Dim _appID As String = "IS"
    Dim _transID As String = "MSSQL01"


    Return gd.getDataTable(_appID, _transID, sql) 'I get the error message here

End Function
End Class
```

Updated. I'll see if I can update with the DataAccess.GetData code. I didn't originally put it in there because our shop use it all the time and have no issues with it.

Comment: What is the value of sql? Is it possible that you are passing Nothing?

Comment: I think you need to post more code, is the error happening inside that function somewhere, or is gd null?  You can tell using the debugger and stopping on that line.

Comment: We don't know the internals of this `GetData` object, and would have no way of answering your question.

Comment: Ok I was thinking maybe the code I posted had a syntax error or I didn't declare "new" when needed. Thanks I'll look at the other parts of the code than.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing what's in `gd.getDataTable`, there's not a lot we can do to help you.  What kind of application are you writing that is calling this function?  Can you put a breakpoint on that line in the editor and step into it to see where the error is occurring?  Otherwise, do you have access to the `DataAccess.GetData` code?  If so, you would get a lot more information from it if you threw the original exception without destroying the stack trace:

**BAD!!!!**

```
Try
    'your code
Catch ex As Exception
    Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
End Try
```

**GOOD:**

```
Try
    'your code
Catch ex As Exception
    Throw
End Try
```